# Supply validation group context with Symfony / API Platform

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

As I said in the title I try to supply the validation context of Sf / Api platform.

More precisely I would like to have different validation groups depending on an entity value.

> If i'm a `User` with `ROLE_PRO` : then i want `validate:pro` and
>   `default` as validation groups.
>
> If i'm a `User` with `ROLE_USER` : then i want `default` as validation
>   group.

I tried to create an event based on the following api-platform event but I can't find a way to supply the `ExecutionContextInterface` with my validation groups

```php
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
     return [
          KernelEvents::VIEW => ['addGroups', EventPriorities::PRE_VALIDATE],
     ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in api-platform documentation (https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/#changing-the-serialization-context-dynamically) you can manipulate validation groups dynamically with a service.

First of all, in your `api-platform` configuration, you have to define default validation group:

```
App\Class\MyClass:
  properties:
    id:
      identifier: true
  attributes:
    input: false
    normalization_context:
      groups: ['default']
```

You need to define a new service which implements `SerializerContextBuilderInterface`

```
class ContextBuilder implements SerializerContextBuilderInterface
{
    private SerializerContextBuilderInterface $decorated;
    private AuthorizationCheckerInterface $authorizationChecker;

    public function __construct(SerializerContextBuilderInterface $decorated, AuthorizationCheckerInterface $authorizationChecker)
    {
        $this->decorated = $decorated;
        $this->authorizationChecker = $authorizationChecker;
    }

    public function createFromRequest(Request $request, bool $normalization, ?array $extractedAttributes = null): array
    {
        $context = $this->decorated->createFromRequest($request, $normalization, $extractedAttributes);

        if (isset($context['groups']) && $this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('ROLE_PRO') && true === $normalization) {
            $context['groups'][] = 'validate:pro';
        }
        return $context;
    }
}
```

Also, you need to configure your new service with a decorator

```
App\Builder\ContextBuilder:
        decorates: 'api_platform.serializer.context_builder'
        arguments: [ '@App\Builder\ContextBuilder.inner' ]
```

What it's happening here is:

You're overriding the ContextBuilder. First of all you create the context from request and from configuration (first line of `createFromRequest` method) and after this, you modify the context depeding of which user is logged.

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you but That's not exactly what I'm looking for. I want to supply the validation context, not the serialization context. And the validation context seems to not be available as a service.